# how to change RGB values of an image

Tags: python, rgb

i want to change the color of a specific part in an image like this image
[image]

i know the coordinates of the bicycle as i want to change its color here's my code

```
def imageprepare(colored,x,y,w,h):
    colored=colored[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
    colored[x:h,y:w,[0,1,2]]=230,142,135
    cv2.imshow('fi',colored)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
imageprepare(original_image,204,28,271, 193)
```

so i got this resulted image

[image]

as u guys see everything is in blue and i want the bicycle only so what seem to be wrong here?

Comment: This line flips R and B channels: `colored=colored[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]`

Comment: "Everything is in blue" because `colored=colored[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]` swaps the blue and red channels of the entire image. No other change occurs because `[x:h, y:w, :]` does not contain any pixels. There are two problems: first, an x-coordinate should be paired with a width and y-coordinate with height (not the other way around); second, these are **slices**, so they should use a start and end point, not a start and a distance. Thus: `[x:x+w, y:y+h, :]`.